# Makefile include directive using nmake

Tags: windows, makefile, nmake

Using nmake from command promp I try to inlcude an Makefile like this

```
OUT = .
include $(OUT)\generated\deps.mk
```

ending up in an fatal error

*fatal error U1052: file '$(OUT)\generated\deps.mk' not found*

replacing the variable with a . i.e. running

```
include .\generated\deps.mk
```

works! What am I doing wrong here? Using nmake included in Visual Studio 12

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself, if using a ! before include statement, or enclosing the path in < > the variable gets expanded

So, either

```
OUT = .
!include $(OUT)\generated\deps.mk
```

or

```
OUT = .
include <$(OUT)\generated\deps.mk>
```

works. And ofcourse both combined